# Accessibility service dispatchGesture swiping the screen not tapping

Tags: java, android, android-service, accessibility

I have been trying to make the accessibility service dispatchGesture with a click and not a swipe.
This code is just swiping down on the screen, and not actually clicking on the x,y cords.

---

What I have tried.

```
Path clickPath = new Path();
clickPath.moveTo(Float.intBitsToFloat(x), Float.intBitsToFloat(y));
GestureDescription.Builder gestureBuilder = new GestureDescription.Builder();
gestureBuilder.addStroke(new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(clickPath, 0, 1));
dispatchGesture(gestureBuilder.build(), null, null);
```

I have also tried replaced the clickPath.moveTo to add clickPath.addCircle, and clickPath.addRect, But both of those just crash the application.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was a few months ago, but from what I've seen, your duration is too short.  I wasn't able to get touch events to register with a duration of less than 50ms.  I also passed a custom handler:

`val handler = Handler(Looper.myLooper()!!)`

It's possible that one or both of these could be the source of the reason it wasn't working for you.  In general, you seem to be doing the same thing that I am, and I'm having some success with it.